# how to make A choice column based on other column?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to make a choice column based on the content of other column. For example, we have three product types in column 1, which are Product 1, Product 2 and Product 3, each product has different defects (in column 2), I want when I choose Product 1, Column 2 will give me defects for Product 1, and when I choose Product 2, Colum 2 will give me defects for Product 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but one option I've seen in the past is (assuming you're using jQuery) using the phenomenal SPServices library.

This is a quick and dirty solution that is all client side. Just follow the code examples from the link below and paste into a Content Editor Web Part on your page.

[SPservices Cascading Dropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)

Hopefully this will get you started.